# Is there a way to load a Crystal Report 9.0 file from a stream?

Tags: delphi, com, crystal-reports, activex

I am working with Delphi and Crystal Reports 9.0 ActiveX objects.

I know that I can load a report from a file like this:

crApplication.OpenReport(AFileName)

However, I would like to store my report in memory and open it from memory instead of file.
I don't want to create any temporary files on my disk.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: bump. I would also like to know this(but for C#) and after a lot of goolging it seems it may not be possible, which is really dumb in my opinion. You'd think the most amazing report writer should have such a thing.

Comment: Totaly agree with you. They are developing CR for years and no one never need such feature? It should be available since ver. 1.0

Comment: But surely you've had to write a report file already, so you wouldn't be creating any temporary files, you're just using your report file? I'm interested in what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: _J_ I want to prevent user from copying my report and use it elsewhere. I could store it in an encrypted file on the hard drive but than I still need to save it after decryption and load via Crystal Report COM object, and during that time user might easly copy my report. If I could load report from stream, I could load an encrypted file from hard drive or database, decrypt it in memory and send it as streem to CR COM object.

Comment: I hope I was somewhat more clear about the subject now. The thing is that after decryption I must save my report on some media(due to the lack of LoadFromStream() method) and user can track that operation and copy temporary file.

Answer (score 2):

This answer comes late, but better late than never...

You can try with a file with attributes FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY and FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE. Such a file is (if enough cache memory is available) not written on harddisk and deleted when your application is closed.

There is an BLOG which describes this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2004/04/19/116084.aspx

And there ist an article here:

[How to create temporary file (0x100) to accelerate application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1082590/645044)

Comment: This is a very nice idea:) However, I think the file still can be copied during the time when application is opened? Anyway, well deserved +1 :)

Comment: Well, not so easy, because the file is only in the cache. Maybe it ist possible, but not without mayor difficulties. 100% security is not possible, every file and data in your computers memory can be copied...