# Delphi - Extract embedded dll from my application and delete it when application ends

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-7

I have embedded my dll file inside my application. I need it to be extracted inside the folder of my application when it starts, and delete it when i close my application. What code should i use?

Comment: you can create a file with `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: im using delphi not  c++

Comment: But your app is running on windows os and you can access the windows api, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082590/how-to-create-temporary-file-0x100-to-accelerate-application

Comment: @SirRufo The file will be deleted as soon as the last handle to it is closed. But you won't be able to keep the file alive long enough to call `LoadLibrary`. If you have any open handles to the file then `LoadLibrary` will fail. So you have to close all open handles in order to all `LoadLibrary` to succeed, but then the file is deleted.

Comment: Best option is then to load the DLL direct from memory http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-load-resource-dll-into-memory.htm

Comment: What about calling `LoadLibrary()` first, than call `CreateFile()` or `SetFileInformationByHandle()` to apply `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Extract the file from the resource like this:

```
var
  Stream: TResourceStream;
....
Stream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, ResourceName, RT_RCDATA);
try
  Stream.SaveToFile(DllFileName);
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

Load the DLL like this:

```
var 
  lib: HMODULE;
....
lib := LoadLibrary(DllFileName);
Win32Check(lib<>0);
```

Call `GetProcAddress` and do whatever you need with the DLL.

When you are finished, unload the DLL and delete the file:

```
FreeLibrary(lib);
DeleteFile(DllFileName);
```

Note that this does mean that you have to use explicit runtime linking (`LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`) rather than implicit load time linking (`external`). There's no way around that if you only have one executable. That's because your code to extract the DLL has to run after the OS loader resolves all the load time dependencies.

Comment: You can use `external` if you also use [`delayed`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Libraries_and_Packages#Delayed_Loading) so the OS does not try to automatically load the DLL at app startup. The DLL will be loaded by the RTL when the DLL is called for the first time. That gives you time to extract it.

Comment: Oh wait, the OP is using Delphi 7, so `delayed` is not an option. It was introduced in Delphi 2010.

Comment: Difficult to see an answer other than this @remy